# How much of a bottleneck will I get with a 3060 Ti and Core i5

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, macbook

I am going to get a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti and an eGPU chassis for my computer. I have a MacBook Air (I Know NVIDIA isn't supported for macOS) and use the eGPU on bootcamp.

I have heard that your CPU can bottleneck GPU performance. The main reason why I am purchasing this GPU is to increase Blender Cycles render times. How much bottleneck will my CPU have on this GPU?

Intel Core i5 8210Y (1.6 GHz, Dual-Core, 4 threads)

8 GB LPDDR3 2133 MHz RAM

MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How much bottleneck will my CPU have on this GPU?

With Blender, probably none, because its done fully on CPU, or fully
on gpu. So if you set the render target to CUDA, it will have gpu speeds, no matter of your CPU speed.

---

CPU frequency is not a measurement of performance. Your Intel i5 Y-Series has aggressive power management maintain strict thermal limitations. The 3.6 GHz turbo speed will only briefly be obtained, most of the time the CPU will be at a slower clock speed. Turbo is not loke overclocked speeds where it is always at the higher clock speed.

For Blendor the CPU is mostly just used to displaying results and dispatching rendering commands to the GPU. This CPU should be fast enough for that task.